# Threads not picking up more work from Queue

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I'm pretty much brand new to python and I have been working on a script that parses the csv files in any given directory. After I implemented a queue and threads, I've been stuck on this issue of the threads not picking up new work, even though there are still items in the queue. For example, if I specify the max # of threads as 3, and there are 6 items in the queue, the threads pick up 3 files, process them, then hang, indefinitely. I may just be conceptually misunderstanding the multithreading process.

ETA:
Some of the code has been removed for security reasons.

```
q = Queue.Queue()
threads = []

for file in os.listdir(os.chdir(arguments.path)):
            if (file.endswith('.csv')):
                q.put(file)
        for i in range(max_threads):
            worker = threading.Thread(target=process, name='worker-{}'.format(thread_count))
            worker.setDaemon(True)
            worker.start()
            threads.append(worker)
            thread_count += 1
        q.join()

def process():
        with open(q.get()) as csvfile:
            #do stuff
            q.task_done()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a to loop over the **Queue** in your threads...

```
def process():
    while True: #<---------------- keep getting stuff from the queue
         with open(q.get()) as csvfile:
         #do stuff
             q.task_done()
```

That said, You are maybe re-inventing the wheel, try using a *Thread Pool*:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

l = [] # a list should do it ...
for file in os.listdir(arguments.path):
        if (file.endswith('.csv')):
            l.append(file)

def process(file):

    return "this is the file i got %s" % file

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as e:
    results = list(e.map(process, l))
```

Comment: Derp. Thank you for that.